# sed vs array vs variable

Tags: bash, loops, sed

Have some `bash` script which contains two arrays:

```
names=( [0]=port_shutdown
        [1]=port_http
        [2]=port_https
        [3]=keystore_file
        [4]=key_alias
        [5]=keystore_pass
        [6]=truststore_file
        [7]=truststore_pass )

value=( [0]="$port_shutdown"
        [1]="$port_http"
        [2]="$port_https"
        [3]="$keystore_file"
        [4]="$key_alias"
        [5]="$keystore_pass"
        [6]="$truststore_file"
        [7]="$truststore_pass" )
```

And variables:

```
port_shutdown="8008"  
port_http="8046"   
port_https="8446"
keystore_file="tomcat.jks"
key_alias="tomcat"
keystore_pass="password"
truststore_file="trustcacerts.jks"
truststore_pass="password"
```

Run it in loop:

```
while [ "$i" -lt "11" ]; do
  name="${names[${i}]}"
  value="${value[${i}]}"
  echo -e "Changing name - "$name" to value "$value";\n"
  sed  's|'"${name}"'|'"${value}"'|g' "server.xml.default" > "server.xml"
  (( i++ ))
done
```

But it doesn't change `names`... Although - it see values in variables:

```
$ ./config.sh
Changing name - port_shutdown to value "8008";

Changing name - port_http to value 8046;

Changing name - port_https to value 8446;

Changing name - keystore_file to value tomcat.jks;

Changing name - key_alias to value tomcat;

Changing name - keystore_pass to value password;

Changing name - truststore_file to value trustcacerts.jks;

Changing name - truststore_pass to value password;
```

If I set for example `name="port_shutdown"` and `value="8008"` - it works good...

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This looks really awkward: `value="${value[${i}]}"`. This set the value of the zero-th field of the array `value` to the expansion of `${value[${i}]}`. Certainly not what you want (yet with no unwanted effects in your snippet).

Answer (score 1):

try maybe

```
sed  "s|${name}|${value}|g" "server.xml.default" > "server.xml"
```

but it is missign something as delimiter (ex: `port_http` will also change `port_https` if array name are in this order)

Comment: Yes, it is, will fix it. Thanks for note.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys...

Let's see what happens with `sed` in this `loop`:

```
sed 's|'"${name}"'|'"${value}"'|g' "server.xml.default" > "server.xml"
```

So - it takes FIRST `$name` and FIRST `$value`, takes content of `server.xml.default`, looking for occurrence (matches?) in it, replace it, save to file `server.xml`. Thats OK.

But at next loop - it takes OLD `server.xml.default`, looking for SECOND `$name` and SECOND `$value`, and... Do same - but in new `server.xml` it save SECOND loop action, but FIRST loop action left unmodified.

So - solution was to create temporary file, wich will save all changes after each loop:

```
i=0
cp server.xml.default server.xml.tmp

while [ "$i" -lt "11" ]; do
  name="${names[${i}]}"
  value="${value[${i}]}"
  echo -e "Changing name - "$name" to value "$value";\n"
  sed  's|'"${name}"'|'"${value}"'|g' server.xml.tmp > server.xml
  cp server.xml server.xml.tmp
  (( i++ ))
  name=
  value=
done
```